# Is there a lower limit to the size of magnetic domains?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, material-science

When reading about magnets synthesized at the nanoscale level, there is plenty of references to spontaneous magnetic order re-orientation; as these materials are too small to have a magnetic domain.
As a result It led me to ponder about how small can magnetic domain's get. Is there an inherent limit per material?

As a side-note, is there any way to maintain fixed ferromagnetism in such small materials without them becoming [super paramagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superparamagnetism)?

Comment: What is "fxed ferromagnetism"?

Comment: Nasu, it means that the magnetization of the material does not randomly flip; i.e: It does not suffer Need relaxation